# Handling double events in accented keyboards

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, jquery-events

I have a special use case where I have a series of input fields, and I switch from the current input field to the other based on the character typed. Its something like a keyword search where keywords are space separated or are enclosed in double quotes. So, as soon as I close a double quote around a word like "India", it should become a keyword and the focus should move to the next input field.

Now, I'm using a Mac with the US - International (PC) keyboard layout which allows me to type accented characters. For example, <kbd>"</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> = ë.

What happens now, is if I type something like "what" and after the second quote, I hit space, the focus moves to the new input field perfectly, BUT, the new input field already has a " character pre-filled in it!

Some debugging showed that this keyboard layout causes two `keyup` events to be fired, one when you type <kbd>"</kbd> and the next when you type <kbd>space</kbd>. The `event.keyCode` for both these events (jQuery) is 229, and in the first case, `event.shiftKey` is true, and its false in the next. The same holds for when you type <kbd>"</kbd> + e, the second `event.keyCode` is 229 again, which doesn't match ë.

That helps me differentiate between the two events, but I'm looking for a more concrete fix for this. As of now, I've not been able to solve this.

If anyone has any ideas, it'll be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself. The idea is to differentiate between the two events based on event.shiftKey. When someone types a double quote and intends to type it, event.shiftKey is true. The second event, after the double quote, if someone presses a character that results in the double quote and the new character being combined to an accented character, the new fired event doesn't have shiftKey = true, but event.keyCode = 229 (which is the same), so this can be used to differentiate. If a new input field still receives a phantom ", amends can be made after such two events are detected.